# UITextView will not set text

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble setting the text in my UITextView. My textView is connected to my storyBoard.  I control dragged to create my outlet.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textView.text = "hello"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
    print(textView.text); //the textView parameter is the textView where text was changed
}

}
```

I expected the string "hello" to appear in the view controller on my simulator but instead I just have a blank screen.  Why don't I see the string?

Comment: Please describe in detail: what do you expect? What is the actual result " it doesn't seem to be working"?

Comment: https://github.com/bryanjcampbell1/practiceTextField

Comment: You have not set any constraints to your textfield and thus do not see it. Storyboard gives you red lines and show errors accordingly. Do not ignore your errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your textview is working fine as far as setting the .text value. The reason it doesn't appear is that your textview has some auto layout constraints missing.

Add a width and height to your textview and it will work.

Comment: That was my issue.  Set width and hight and everything worked fine.  Gracias.

Comment: Setting constraints didn't work for me but setting a frame (either at initialization or through the property) did

Answer (score 0):

Check if the textcolor is same as textview's background color.