# Store user input and show into UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, user-input

I'm currently teaching myself in Swift and Xcode.

At the moment I'm trying to get some user input over a UITextField and I want to store them in an Array. The array should go through a for-loop to show the stored data in a UITextView.

At the start I tried it with one user input. It worked.

```
@IBOutlet weak var InputPlayerName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SubmitPlayer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ShowPlayerName: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var ShowSize: UITextView!

var players = [String]()

@IBAction func SubmittedPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
    players.append(ShowPlayerName.text);

    let playerssize = players.count;

    ShowSize.text = "\(playerssize)";

    for player in players {
        if(playerssize == 1) {
            ShowPlayerName.text = "Player: \n \(player)";
        } else {
            ShowPlayerName.text += "\(player)";
        }
    }
```

I don't get any errors, it just doesn't show me the results. But the arraysize grows if I press the button.

How can I show the Data line per line in the View?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but don't end lines with `;` in Swift. And it is standard for variable, function, and case names to start with lowercase letters. Class/struct/enum names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524691/5464805. It may be a constraint issue for your `UITextView`.